# Run Craft Find and Replace via Console

Tags: craft-features, console

I'm trying to streamline my deployments for local, staging and production and would like to know if it's possible to invoke the Find and Replace method via Console. I have a multi-config in place, but I'd like to ensure that any hardcoded urls are replaced in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a plugin that does this.

Use https://pluginfactory.io/ and check the "Console Command" checkbox and it will generate the boilerplate for you.

Your "Find and Replace" command would follow similar logic to what the [FindAndReplaceTask](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/tasks/FindAndReplaceTask.php#L108)'s `runStep()` method does.